# Does it make sense to use ObjectController and ArrayController together?

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of object, stored in an arrayController and rendered on the view using the `#each` macro

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  {{view App.ItemView}}
{{/each}}
```

Each item view has class name binding that depends on the user action. For exemple :

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend {
  classNameBindings: ['isSelected:selected']
}
```

`isSelected`depends on the state of each Item : I have to store the selected item somewhere, and compare it to the new selected item if a click event is triggered.

The question is: where should I compute this `isSelected`property ? In the `itemsController` ? In an `itemController`? Directly in each itemView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it does make sense to put it into the view as, moreover, it is really a display concern.

You've got an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/r6xcA/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    {{#each item in controller}}
        {{view App.ItemView contentBinding="item"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    Item: {{item.label}}
</script>
```

**​JavaScript**:

```js
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    selected: null
});

App.ItemsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'items'
});

App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'item',
    classNameBindings: ['isSelected:selected'],

    isSelected: function() {
        var item = this.get('content'),
            selected = this.getPath('controller.selected');
        return item === selected;
    }.property('item', 'controller.selected'),

    click: function() {
        var controller = this.get('controller'),
            item = this.get('content');
        controller.set('selected', item);
    }
});

App.ItemsView.create({
    controller: App.ItemsController.create({
        content: [{ label: 'My first item' },
                  { label: 'My second item' },
                  { label: 'My third item' }]
    })
}).append();
​
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. Just one more question: I can't see when the `controller`object is set into the App.ItemView ?

Comment: In the sample, it is set at view creation. In 'real life', it would be auto-bound in `connectOutlet`.

Comment: @jrabary I think the controller you mention here is the implicit controller of the children views. If so, in this case, it is inherited from the ItemsView.

Comment: I think this solution is fine for the use case described. However, if any additional properties or logic related to the select object comes up, you should refactor to add a separate ObjectController named itemController or selectedItemController and use it's content property to track the selected item.

Comment: That's absolutely true. As you can notice: I only intended to provide a short answer limited to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need two things - an `isSelected` property on the item itself (the model) which answers the question, "Is this item selected?", and a `selectedItem` property on the `itemsController`, which answers the question, "Which item is selected?" The property on the model is just a get/set; you could compute `itemsController.selectedItem` by filtering the list of items for one where `isSelected` is true, or you could set it explicitly with some code to un-select previously unselected items.

Comment: This was my first thought but I don't want to clutter my model with additional properties other than those I persist in my database. Hence, I'd like to proxy these properties to an itemController derived from Ember.ObjectController.

Comment: I don't mind `isSelected` attribute on the item is a good idea as it has certainly nothing to deal with the model attributes, being only a display state information.

Comment: From the documentation: "We start with controllers rather than exposing the model objects directly to your templates so that you have someplace to put view-related computed properties and don't end up polluting your models with view concerns."