# Toggle sibling item controller property

Tags: ember.js, controller

I'm trying to toggle a property on sibling item controllers. From what I've read, I need to go through the parent controller and then set the property for each item controller.

For the example below, when a user clicks on an food item, it expands the types. I then want it to toggle the 'opacity' property on all sibling item controllers.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'type',

  actions: {
      unselectedOpacity: function(t){
        // select children controller
        // except for clicked item
        // set 'opacity' property
      }
  }
})

App.TypeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  show: false,

  actions: {
   showit: function(){
      this.toggleProperty('show')

      this.get('parentController').send('unselectedOpacity', this)
    }
  }
})
```

Actual code on [my jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yufakekuye/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it make sense to use ObjectController and ArrayController together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209740/does-it-make-sense-to-use-objectcontroller-and-arraycontroller-together)

Comment: My issue is toggling a property on each item controller, not class binding necessarily.

Comment: It still applies, you can change the property of model in the view, the example uses classes, but the logic behind its the same. only the `selected` type would have a property in true, while the others will be false. an array controller does not really have access to the itemControllers. you can try to use `needs` but that is not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out - I could just use `this.setEach()` in the controller.

I don't think I worded the initial question too well. What I was looking for was a way to change the property of sibling controllers and the current controller simultaneously.

[my JSbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nujagubuca/1/edit?html,js,output) - I still gotta clean up the code though.